# click button not working in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am generating modal box dynamically. In that modal i have two button. Yes & No.
No will close the modal and that is working properly.
I am facing problem while clicking on Yes button.

Once user click on Yes it will update the database.
Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
$("#btnYes1").on("submit", function(e) {    
//  $('#btnYes1').click(function (e) {    
//$('#btnYes1').click(function() {
      e.preventDefault();
    alert('working');
});
});
</script>
```

Code used to generate Modal box. You can see i tried 2-3 things but it is not working.

```
var modalval='<a href="#" id="btnYes1" name="btnYes1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-success">Yes</a>';
                    modalval += '<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-danger">No</a>';    $('#modaltext').append(modalval);
```

Comment: Build a complete example (and it's not really clear what your issue is...)

Comment: If you do it dynamicly try do $('body').on('click', '#btnYes1', function(){your code here});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the event listener to your `document` instead.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnYes1", function(e) {
    // Your code..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery will run only once - when the page is first loaded. The "btnYes1" element does not exist at that point.

You need to register the event after the modal has been generated and the button is on the page.

```
// after modal has been generated
$("#btnYes1").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('working');
});
```

For example, put that code in the success from the AJAX call that loads the modal.